# limit of harmonic functions Gilbarg and Trudinger page 27

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Here is a passage from Gilbarg and Trudinger page 27

Let $\Sigma$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n\geq 3$) with smooth boundary $\partial\Omega$, and let $u$ be the harmonic function (often called conductor potential) defined in the complement of $\bar{\Omega}$ and satisfying the boundary conditions $u=1$ on $\partial\Omega$ and $u=0$ at infinity. **The existence of $u$ is easily established as the (unique) limit of harmonic functions $u'$ in an expanding sequence of bounded domains having $\partial\Omega$ as an inner boundary (on which $u'=1$)** and with outer boundaries (on which $u'=0$) tending to infinity. If $\Sigma$ denotes $\partial\Omega$ or any smooth closed surface enclosing $\Omega$, then the quantity

$$\text{cap }\Omega = -\int_{\underset{\bar{}}{v}}\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}\text{d}s = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n-\Omega} |Du|^2\text{d}x\quad v= \text{outer normal}$$

is defined to be the capacity of $\Omega$.

1) I do not understand why the part in bold is obviously true?

2) In the definition of capacity, I do not really understand what the first integral really mean and why does it equals to the second integral. My guess is integration by parts of some sort, but it is not obvious to me.

Comment: Regarding the first part, I get the existence of the limit of the $u'$ without problem. But showing that it vanishes at infinity, I don't know yet how to.

Comment: @DanielFischer you are welcome to post a partial answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning the first question, let us denote the domains by $G_n$, and the outer boundary of $G_n$ by $S_n$, and let $u_n$ be the harmonic function on $G_n$ with boundary conditions $u_n = 1$ on $\partial \Omega$ and $u_n = 0$ on $S_n$.

Then by the maximum principle, we have $0 \leqslant u_n \leqslant 1$ on $G_n$. Consequently, $u_{n+1}(x) \geqslant 0$ for all $x \in S_n$. Thus $u_{n+1}\lvert_{G_n} - u_n$ is a harmonic function on $G_n$ with boundary values $0$ on $\partial \Omega$ and $\geqslant 0$ on $S_n$. Therefore $u_{n+1}\lvert_{G_n} - u_n \geqslant 0$ on $G_n$.

Thus for every $x \in G_n$, the sequence $(u_m(x))_{m \geqslant n}$ is monotonically increasing (not necessarily strictly), and bounded ($u_m(x) \leqslant 1$).

So $u(x) = \lim u_n(x)$ is well-defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \overline{\Omega}$. Use your favourite argument to conclude that $u$ is harmonic. Harnack's inequality shows that a monotonic sequence of harmonic functions converges locally uniformly, for example. Or use that the limit has the mean value property by the monotone convergence theorem.

It is clear that $u$ has boundary values $1$ on $\partial \Omega$. It remains to be seen that $\lim\limits_{\lVert x\rVert\to\infty} u(x) = 0$.

The credit for [the argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847366/limit-of-harmonic-functions-gilbarg-and-trudinger-page-27#comment1748197_847598) for that goes to [Tomás](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/42394/tom%c3%a1s).

We choose an $r > 0$ such that $\Omega \subset B_r(0)$, and let $v(x) = \dfrac{r^{n-2}}{\lVert x\rVert^{n-2}}$. $v$ is harmonic and satisfies $v(x) = 1$ on $\partial B_r(0)$ and $v(\infty) = 0$. For $n$ large enough, $\overline{B_r(0)} \subset G_n$, and then $v - u_n$ is harmonic on $G_n\setminus \overline{B_r(0)}$ with boundary values $1 - u_n(x) \geqslant 0$ on $\partial B_r(0)$ and $v(x) - 0 \geqslant 0$ on $S_n$, hence $u_n \leqslant v$ on $G_n\setminus \overline{B_r(0)}$. It follows that $0 \leqslant u(x) \leqslant v(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \overline{B_r(0)}$, and hence $\lim\limits_{\lVert x\rVert\to\infty} u(x) = 0$.

Comment: very nice, thanks a lot.

Comment: Using the fact $u(x)$ is continuous. By Dini's theorem, if a monotone sequence of continuous function converging to a continuous function, then the convergence must be uniform. pick an $N$ large enough such that for all $x$, $|u(x)-u_N(x)|<\epsilon$, then pick $y$ large enough such that $|u_N(x)|=0$ for $||x||>||y||$

Comment: Duh, yes. We need to add the point at infinity to get a compact domain, but then it works. Very good observation!

Comment: you did the hard bit. thanks once again.

Comment: Argh. Unfortunately, it does not work. For Dini's theorem, we need a compact domain. So we need to attach a point at infinity. But then the continuity of the limit function in $\infty$ is just what we want to show :(

Comment: i will remove the tick for a while so that it stays unanswered, for a couple of more days

Comment: This is probably a stupid question. For a given $u_n(x)$, is it necessarily the case the $\Delta u_n(x)=0$ for $x\in S_n$? I assume not because $u_n$ might not even have first derivatives?

Comment: Right, on the boundary part $S_n$, we don't know whether $u_n$ behaves nicely beyond continuity. But would we gain anything if $u_n$ could be extended harmonically past $S_n$?

Comment: probably not, no.

Comment: Fix some $r>0$ such that, $\overline{\Omega}\subset B(0,r)$ and consider the exterior problem on the annulus (with same boundary conditions) $\{x:\ r<|x|<R\}$, for $R>r$. If $u_{r,R}$ is the solution for this problem, then $\Delta(u-u_{r,R})=0$ and $u(x)\le u_{r,R}(x)=1$ for $|x|=r$. Therefore, the maximum principles implies that $u(x)\le u_{r,R}(x)$ for all $r\le |x|\le R$. To conclude, note that $u_{r,R}$ has a particular expression.

Comment: @Tomás Brilliant simple idea. Thanks a ton.

Comment: You are welcome @DanielFischer, but please, the credit is not only mine. I probably read it somewhere in some book.

Comment: @Tomás Yes, but remembering the right thing at the right time is worthy of credit. Shall I edit to make it "the credit for remembering the argument", or can it stand as it is now?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Leave it in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I have now obtained the answer for the second part from a friend.

$\int_V \nabla u.\nabla u\text{d}V= \int_V \nabla (u\nabla u)-u\nabla^2 u \text{d}V = \int_S u\nabla u.n\text{d}s-0=-\int_v \frac{\partial u}{\partial v}\text{d}s$

where $\nabla^2 u =0$ by harmonicity and the last line follws because the normals $n$ is pointing in the opposite direction to the definition.